# iPhone:Event when start video recording button clicked?

Tags: iphone

I like to know, are there any events can get triggered in our program whenever user is clicking on Camera start/stop buttons to record/stop the video?

From my application, it is possible to launch Video camera and start video recording and come back with the recorded video. I am using UIImagePickerController and didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo to get the data. It works fine. I want to handle something whenever user starts the video recording by clicking on built-in camera start button. Is it possible?

Please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using `UIImagePickerController`'s default interface. You could however create a custom view (including a record button) and show it over the controller using the `cameraOverlayView` property. When the user presses your custom record button, call `start/stopVideoCapture`—this would provide you with the information you're after.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any sample for this?

Comment: This blog post looks promising: http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/10/custom-video-overlay-view-on-the-iphone/

Comment: If i don't use overlay, Is there no way i can catch "Start" camera button click in my code as event or notification? If i use overlay, i'll not get "Use" "Retake" buttons after recording the video. And also, i will not get recording timer as well. I want to go with using UIImagePickerController itself and use presentModalViewController and try to catch camera "start" events.

Comment: You cannot catch the button clicks without using an overlay. If you want the retake/use buttons, etc. you will need to implement them yourself.

Comment: Ok, thank you Chris. One last question, after recording the video etc. as you have suggested i can place "Use" and "Retake" buttons in my overlay itself, may be i can change the button titles otherwise Apple may reject. I want to know what will happen to PickerView delegate methods? Will also that be called even though if i use overlay?

Comment: `didCancel:` will not be called, `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` will be called each time you call `stopVideoCapture` (i.e. if the user chooses to retake the video, it will be called again). I suggest you look at Apple's PhotoPicker example. It uses a custom overlay and can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html